# What match pattern does //* target?

Tags: xslt

Trying to rewrite an XSLT file and just not sure what the match pattern is targeting.

I know that /* targets the top element of an XML document, but I have no clue what this pattern does. This is the line.

```
<xsl:key name="ids" match="//*" use="@xml:id"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `//*` in a `select` expression would select all element nodes in the whole document.

In a `match` expression (for a template or key) there's no point in using the leading `//`, as both `match="//*"` and `match="*"` would match exactly the same nodes, namely any element anywhere in the document.

`//` is nothing more nor less than a textual shorthand for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`, so `//*` means `/descendant-or-self::node()/*`, or any element which is a child of the document node or of any descendant thereof.

Answer (score 2):

The xpath pattern [//](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/xml/xpath.xtp#root-descendant)[*](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/xml/xpath.xtp#star) match all elements of the document